# Wordpress WooCommerce same size on all thumbnails

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm currently creating a WordPress site but having huge problems on getting all thumbnails to the same size. 
What I've done is the following: `WooCommerce > Settings > Products > Style > hard crop at 300x400` and then regenerate the thumbnails but it won't work..

Correct image

[image]

Incorrect image

[image]

The thing is that it works with like 90% of the pictures but some still got the same problem and the image dimensions are always higher than 300x400 that I'm using now.

Comment: May be you uploade some images less than 300x400